# Regex to detect whitespace inside my words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match my timestamp format, but I need to detect whether it is invalid format or not (I need to do something about the invalid format)

Currently, I need to match a space character inside my timestamp:

examples:

```
[02:21.10,E] or [02:21.10,C#] //correct format
[02:21.10, E] or [10.21.10,E ]  //incorrect format, there is a space, but i need to match it with my incorrectRegex
```

for my correct regex, I use this regex and it is valid:

```
/\[(\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d),(.*?)\]/g
```

and for my incorrect regex, I use

```
/\[\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d,\s*?\]/g
```

but it didn't find any match for my incorrect format

nb: I'm using a javascript

Comment: not sure if this works in Javascript but how about `[ ]` ?(notice the space inside the brackets)

Comment: actually, i need to match the invalid format, so i would like to do something about that format, when i use ur regex, it doesn't match if there is a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[\d\d[.:]\d\d[.:]\d\d,(?:[ ][^\]]+?|[^\]]+?[ ])\]
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7YrGk/4).

```js
var re = /\[\d\d[.:]\d\d[.:]\d\d,(?:[ ][^\]]+?|[^\]]+?[ ])\]/;

console.log(re.test('[02:21.10,E]'));;
console.log(re.test('[02:21.10,C#]'));
console.log(re.test('[02:21.10, E]'));
console.log(re.test('[10.21.10,E ]'));
console.log(re.test('[10.21.10,C# ]'));
console.log(re.test('[02:54.97,C#]single[02:55.61,A ]'));
```

PS: I assume it is not an error that your second invalid sample `[10.21.10,E ]` does not contain a `:` after the first two digits. I have applied the same for the second dot/colon.

Comment: it almost works!!

but when i try to combine it with my correct regex, sometimes the invalid format is match for the correct format, so sometimes the incorrect format is marked as a green color 

just a step further, maybe i should revise my correct regex now ?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine it with my correct regex"? Is this a separate question? The answer is about to match the invalid format.

Comment: yeah, it is a separate regex, but i'm using plugin to match the correct regex and incorrect regex, since your incorrect regex is valid, i will mark your question as answered

Comment: sorry, but when i set this string, it got weird because it matches certain character outside the `[]` 

"[02:54:47]A [02:54.97,C#]single[02:55.61,A ] thing you do to[02:58.04,B#]nig[02:59.34,E]ht [02:59.95,B]"

the match found is: `[02:54.97,C#]single[02:55.61,A ]` when using your regex, it is a little step further to finish this.